# Find duplicate elements in an array

Tags: php

I got an array of coins with many details, that looks partially like that:

```
array(360) {
  ["VEN/USDT"]=>
  array(15) {
    ["tierBased"]=>
    bool(false)


    }
    ["id"]=>
    string(7) "VENUSDT"
    ["symbol"]=>
    string(8) "VEN/USDT"
    ["base"]=>
    string(3) "VEN"
    ["quote"]=>
    string(4) "USDT"


    ["lot"]=>
    float(0.01)
    ["active"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
```

All I need is this part:

```
["id"]=>
string(7) "VENUSDT"
["symbol"]=>
string(8) "VEN/USDT"
["base"]=>
string(3) "VEN"
["quote"]=>
string(4) "USDT"
```

if "base" is more often than once in the entire array.

Comment: You're looking for duplicates, or you want to remove the duplicates?

Comment: I need the duplicates ("VEN", "ABC", ...) and then extract these 4 elements into a database. This database record will be expanded with other data from other sites.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Show us your code.

Comment: I overlooked that is a nested array. $base_array = array();
foreach ($markets as $key=>$value) {
 echo "1. Key = " . $key . "\n";
 foreach ($value as $key => $value) {
  if ($key == "base") {
   echo "Base = " . $value . "\n";
   array_push($base_array, $value);
  }
 }
}

Comment: However, this doesn't work yet: $unique = array_unique($base_array);
$duplicates = array_diff_assoc($base_array, $unique);
var_dump($duplicates);

Comment: Please add the code to your question by clicking on the edit button beneath it.

Comment: I am done. I forgot to use $duplicates = array_unique($duplicates1);  - How to go to chat????

Answer (score 1):

The final code was:

```
$base_array = array();
foreach ($markets as $key=>$value) {
    echo "1. Key = " . $key . "\n";
    foreach ($value as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == "base") {
            echo "Base = " . $value . "\n";
            array_push($base_array, $value);
        }
    }
}


// Duplicates we need only!
$unique = array_unique($base_array);
$duplicates1 = array_diff_assoc($base_array, $unique);
$duplicates = array_unique($duplicates1);

var_dump($duplicates);
```